# Weka exception: No source has been specified

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line, machine-learning, weka

I am trying to use weka from ubuntu command line, however, when I execute the following command:

```
java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t /data/iris.ARFF
```

Then, I get

```
Weka exception: No source has been specified
```

Following it, there are a detail explanation of the usage, but I do not think I use it wrongly, since all the websites are talking about using WEKA in that way.

Could someone please help me about this?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: You're sure the file exists? I'm only asking because of the uppercase ARFF, Linux file systems are usually case-sensitive. I also read somewhere that Weka has problems with uppercase ARFF filename extensions, try renaming them to lowercase. btw: which version of Weka are you using?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried lower case first and it does work. Then I change it to this way. I think the version is 3.6.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found out the reason myself.
Only on Linux.

There should not be a leading '/' in the path of .arff file.
So the correct way should be:

```
java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t data/iris.ARFF
```

instead of

```
java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t /data/iris.ARFF
```

Comment: This is not strictly true, certainly not for mac users anyway. The documentation states that you need to execute the file from the directory where WEKA is located. Whilst this may be true the full path needs to be given to the file location as such `java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t /Applications/weka-3-6-10/data/weather.nominal.arff`